# Seating Problem ( Permutations and Combinations )

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

What is the number of ways seating three gentleman and three ladies in a row such that each gentleman is adjacent to one lady ?

My attempt - My attempt was to first make three groups each containing a gentleman and a lady and then arrange them. 
This leads to $ 3!\times2\times2\times2 $ since the number of ways in which groups can be arranged themselves is $3!$ and then members of each of three groups have two possible arrangements .

Then I multiplied this by the number of ways in which such groups can be formed which is $3!\times3!$.

Hence the answer I got was $1728$ , which is no where close to the answer given in the problem which is $360$.

Where am I going wrong ?

Is there a easier method to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method both under and over counts.  It undercounts by neglecting patterns like $GGBBGB$, it overcounts by both permuting and then repopulating patterns.  If, instead, you skip the permutations (which can all be realized through the later repopulation) you would get $2^3\times 3!\times 3!=288$ which is the correct answer (if you disallow the two patterns $GGBBGB,\;BGBBGG$)

The hard part is to get all the possible patterns.  I'll do that here:

By looking at the possible strings,starting with $B=boy$, there are five possible types of arrangements:  $$\{BGGBGB,\;BGGBBG,\;BGBGBG,\;BGBGGB,\;BGBBGG\}$$

Starting with $G=girl$ we also have five possible arrangements, namely $$\{GBBGBG,\;GBBGGB,\;GBGBGB,\;GBGBBG,\;GGBBGB\}$$

Each of these can be populated in $3!\times 3!=36$ ways, hence $360$.

To elaborate on the counting:

Case I. say we start with $B$.  Then the next has to be $G$.

Ia.  $BGG...$.  Fourth must be $B$, whence $BGGB$  but then either $\fbox {BGGBBG}$ or $\fbox {BGGBGB}$ work.

Ib.  $BGB...$.  We could have $BGBB$ in which case we must have $\fbox {BGBBGG}$ or we could have $BGBG$ win which case we could have either $\fbox {BGBGGB}$ or $\fbox{BGBGBG}$.

Case II (starting with $G$) is similar.

Comment: So if we break the population into three groups as described above , then the total number of permutations will be 3 ! ( The number of ways we can arrange the three groups ) * 8 ( The number of ways the members within the groups can be arranged since each possible arrangement leads to a new permutation ) .

Comment: I didn't quite understand your approach , why are you starting with fixing either the gentleman or the lady at the front , plus how did you get ten possible arrangements after that ( In the fifth iteration with the brackets you have used four X's , maybe that is a typo ? )

Comment: What are you trying to count with your $3!\times 2^3$?  If you are trying to count the patterns, then it is wrong...because you can have things like $GBGGBBG$.  You are correct, that there is a problem with my enumeration, I am fixing it now.

Comment: How is the pattern that you mentioned wrong , each gentleman is sitting next to attest one lady in it !

Also now that you have fixed the enumeration , the last two terms are exactly the same !!

Comment: Also could you explain you technique further ? . I still haven't gotten the hang of it.

Comment: My count was flawed because I included one case with $4$ gentlemen.  I think the correct version is correct.  Note:  the problem only requires each boy to be next to a girl, it does not require each girl to be next to a boy.  Is that what was intended?

Comment: Yes , only that each boy be next to a girl that is all that is needed , and in your case GBGGBBG , each boy is next to a girl. 
I don't understand how is what I am doing giving me extra cases

Comment: That case has four girls, that's the problem.  I've expanded my answer...see if it helps.

Comment: I still don't understand how your count is meant to work.  Try it with two couples.  Now the patterns are $BGGB, BGBG,GBGB,GBBG$.  What does your count give?

Comment: Thanks a lot your extended answer helps me understand much better. Now get how you are approaching the problem , first you are figuring out all the possible arrangement and then seeing all the ways to populate them . 

Now in case of two my method gives the answer 8 * 2 rather ( 2*2*2) * 2 first form the two groups , then arrange them that gives us 2 ways then since each one of them can be changed from within in two ways we get 2*2 hence we get 8 .
No we find the number of ways in which groups can be formed which is 2 
So answer is sixteen
Is sixteen the correct answer in this case ?

Comment: By my method I get $4$ patterns, as listed in my earlier comment, and there are $2\times 2=4$ ways to populate each.  Hence $4\times 4=16$ so I agree with you here.  To be clear:  I think the hard part is enumerating the patterns.  Easy to populate any given pattern, but it is hard to see how many patterns there are.

Comment: I agree with you, enumeration the patterns is the harder part . 
So that is why in my method i try to avoid it completely by first breaking down the problem into the desired groups and arranging them and then seeing the number of ways i could have formed the initial groups . 

However, much to my frustration  I still don't realise where am I going wrong here !!!

Comment: But some patterns aren't allowed, yes?  I mean, you can't look at the groups $(B_1,G_1), (B_2,G_1), (B_3,G_1)$ say because $G_1$ can, at most, be next to two boys.  Also, even if you have $(B_1,G_1), (B_2,G_1), (B_3,G_2)$ you have to take into account that "sharing" $G_1$ as a neighbor means you must have either $\{B_1G_1B_2\}$ or $\{B_2G_1B_1\}$.  So the "arrangements" of the chosen couples depend crucially, and non-trivially, on the overlaps.

Comment: Hmm I see that some of my groups may not be allowed , could point out any specific group that results from the method which isn't allowed . 
I see that you tried to do that earlier but i don't understand how is that related , since I didn't specifically mention sharing anywhere !

Comment: Well, sharing is possible, as in the pattern $BGBBGG$ so that has to show up somewhere in your enumeration.  But I still don't follow your calculation.  if you have "populated" the patterns from the start, why are you multiplying by $36$ at the end?  In my case, the factor of $36$ represents the number of ways to populate any pattern.  What is it in your case?

Comment: Oh!  I finally understood your method. First of all, you miss all the "sharing" cases. Second, and more serious, you fix a choice of groups and then you permute and then you multiply by the choices, but there is significant overlap here.  If your first arrangement is $B_1G_1B_2G_2B_3G_3$ and your second is $B_2G_2B_1G_1B_3G_3$ then did I get from the first to the second by permuting the first or by reassigning the original couples?  That's the way you overcount.  You can skip the permutations which then gets you 288 cases (no sharing).  You have to then do the sharing cases separately.